Remove bone rotation limit?
What generates this rotation limit display (picture attached) for bones?  I have removed the "Limit Rotation" constraint from the bone but the display remains.  I can manually rotate the bone past the limit now, but I would like to remove the display.


Select the bone in Pose mode and in the Bone panel > Inverse Kinematics > check the Limit X, Y and Z:


Thank you, that was exactly what I needed.   Very clear illustration, also.
